# How to update Sale Order Status in custom database Magento 2

Tags: orders, sales-order, order-status

I am taking an order from an observer. its current order status "pending" is displaying in my custom table but after the invoice is done.... the order status "processing" is not changed in my database table.

Observer Code:

```
<?php
namespace Progos\Assignment\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderStatusUpdate implements ObserverInterface
{
public function __construct()
{
// Observer initialization code...
// You can use dependency injection to get any class this observer may need.
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
    foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $name = $item->getName();
        $type = $item->getSku();
        $id = $item->getProductId();
        $qty = $item->getQty();
        $status=$item->getGrandTotal();

        echo $name.'<br>'.'<br>'.$type.'<br>'.'<br>'.$id.'<br>'.'<br>'.$qty.'<br>'.'<br>'.$status;

    }
    echo "heelooooo";exit();
}
}
```

Customer Grid Form Code:

```
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_form_grid.customer_form_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">customer_form_grid.customer_form_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="customer_form_grid_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customer_form_grid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="customer_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>

    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <!-- Entity ID -->
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Entity ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="customer_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="order_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="points">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Points</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="dateadded">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Dated Added</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="dateupdated">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Date Updated</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

    </columns>
</listing>
```

Event File:

```
<event name="sales_order_invoice_pay">
        <observer name="observer_controller_status_update"
                  instance="Progos\Assignment\Observer\OrderStatusUpdate"/>
    </event>
```

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: This is the Code. For my grid and observer.

Comment: what event name did you use?

Comment: event name="sales_order_invoice_pay"

Comment: I have changed the observer.... i am now able to get other values but not the status neither amount nor grand total.